# Finding moment estimator

Tags: statistics, moment-generating-functions, parameter-estimation

I am required for a homework question to find moment and maximum likelihood estimators, and in class we have only looked at finding MLEs and using already known moment estimators, hence I have no idea how to find the moment estimator myself. I have looked it up and done a little research, but I simply have no idea how go start. Is there some formula?

Sorry I don't want to post the question on fear of plagiarism concerns.

Comment: The population moments are known functions of the parameters you're trying to estimate.  Suppose there are $k$ of those, $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$.  Set the first $k$ population moments, which are the aforementioned functions of $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$, equal to the first $k$ sample moments.  That gives you a set of equations to solve for $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy so I want $E(X) \dots E(X^k)$ = my k sample moments, using my distribution(binomial) for each of the E(X) moments. Are these population moments known because I have a distribution of iid variables and can thus workout these E(X), or would I normally have been given these?

Comment: If there are parameters you are trying to estimate, the presumably each tuple of values of those parameters corresponds to some known probability distribution.  Say you have a Gamma distribution $\displaystyle\text{constant}\cdot (x/\beta)^{\alpha-1} e^{-x/\beta}(dx/\beta)$.  You want to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Given the density, you can find the population moments $\mathbb E(X)$ and $\mathbb E(X^2)$ as functions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Set those equal to the sample moments $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and $(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)/n$, then solve the resulting equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: For the given Gamma distribution, the population moments are $\mathbb E(X)=\alpha\beta$ and $\mathbb E(X^2) = \alpha (\alpha+1) \beta^2$.  So you have $\alpha\beta=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and $\alpha(\alpha+1)\beta^2=(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)/n$.  Solve those for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and that gives you the estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Sorry for not responding. This was definitely helpful. Thank you very much for these comments. They would suffice as a perfect answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are parameters you are trying to estimate, the presumably each tuple of values of those parameters corresponds to some known probability distribution. For example, suppose you have a Gamma distribution

$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)} \left(\frac x \beta\right)^{\alpha−1} e^{−x/\beta} \left(\frac{dx} \beta \right).$$

You want to estimate $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Given the density, you can find the population moments $\mathbb E(X)$ and $\mathbb E(X^2)$ as functions of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Set those equal to the sample moments $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and $(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)/n$, then solve the resulting equations for $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

For the given Gamma distribution, the population moments are $\mathbb E(X)=αβ$ and $\mathbb E(X^2)=α(α+1)\beta^2$. So you have $αβ=(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ and $\alpha(\alpha+1)\beta^2=(X_1^2+\cdots+X_n^2)/n$. Solve those for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and that gives you the estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.